# python list random sampling all configurations

Tags: python

Currently I have a list with 300 elements and I am sampling 100 elements at random from this list.

```
list = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', ..... , 'Z']

n = 100
random_choices = random.sample(list, n)    
random_choices
```

Instead of random sampling, I want to create a single list for every single possible configuration of 100 out of 300.

The result should be a 2 dimensional array:

```
list = [[sample list 1], [sample list 2],...., [sample list N]]
```

How would I go about this?  Thank you

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: There are 4 x 10^81 ways to sample 100 elements from 300...that is about the number of atoms in the universe. This is not feasible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dont. According to https://www.mathsisfun.com/combinatorics/combinations-permutations-calculator.html there are 4.1582514632e+81 possible permutations without repetitions and duplicates for 100 over 300.

There is simply no way to store that much. If you used a generator for that - what would you do with it? Even all computers on earth combined would not be able to make a dent computationally into those permutations.